# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los valores de un vector se sumen entre si?

Tags: c++, vectores

Estoy tratando de realizar este código, el mayor problema que he encontrado es hacer que los valores, se sumen entre si para determinar si el valor final es 1.

Una matriz de probabilidad es una matriz cuadrada que tiene dos propiedades:
(a) Todos sus elementos son no negativos.
(b) La suma de los elementos en cada renglón es 1.
Determine si una matriz dada es una matriz de probabilidad.

Solo llevo esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>vect;
    
    int num;
    std::cout << "Introduce el tamaño deseado: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
        {
            float numero;
            std::cout << "Introduce los numeros deseados: ";
            std::cin >> numero;
            
            vect.push_back(numero);
            
            if (numero < 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Su matriz no es una matriz de probabilidad.";
            }  
            
            if (numero = 1) 
            {
                std::cout << "Su matriz es una matriz de probabilidad.";
            }     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seria muy bueno que pusieras un ejemplo real para entenderte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Después de insertar los números en tu matriz debes poner esto:

```
float Sumatoria = 0;
bool matrizDeProbabilidad = true;

// filas y columnas serían las filas y columnas que tendría tu matriz, como la matriz es cuadrada puedes usar solamente una.
for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
{ 
   if(matrizDeProbabilidad == false)
   {
      break;
   }

   Sumatoria = 0;
          
   for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
   {
      if(matriz[i, j] >= 0)
      {
         Sumatoria += matriz[i, j];
      }
      else
      {
         matrizDeProbabilidad = false;
         break;
      }
   }       

   if(Sumatoria != 1)
   {
      matrizDeProbabilidad = false;
      break;
   }
}

if(matrizDeProbabilidad)
{
   //Imprimir es una matriz de probabilidad
}
else
{
   //Imprimir no es una matriz de probabilidad
}
```

Se declaran dos variables:

**Sumatoria**: Almacena la suma de cada fila de la matriz, es de tipo **float**.

**matrizDeProbabilidad**: **Variable booleana** que indica si la matriz es o no una matriz de probabilidad.

Se hacen **dos ciclos for anidados**, dentro del ciclo exterior se pregunta si la **variable matrizDeProbabilidad** es **false**, de serlo quiere decir que no estamos ante una matriz de probabilidad por lo que ejecutamos un **break** para salir del ciclo. De ser **true** pues se le da a la **variable Sumatoria** el valor de **0**.

Dentro del ciclo interno se pregunta si la celda que estamos analizando tiene un número positivo, de tenerlo pues se lo sumamos a la **variable Sumatoria**, de no serlo pues la **variable matrizDeProbabilidad** tomará el valor de **false** y se saldrá del ciclo interno mediante un **break**.

Si hasta este momento la **variable matrizDeProbabilidad** sigue siendo **true** entonces preguntamos si la **variable Sumatoria** es diferente de **1**, de serlo **matrizDeProbabilidad** será **false** y se terminará el ciclo mediante un **break**.

Después de salir de los dos ciclos se pregunata si **matrizDeProbabilidad** es **true**, de serlo se imprime que es una matriz de probabilidad, de no serlo se imprime que no es una matriz de probabilidad.

Answer (score 0):

De hecho pude desarrollar la respuesta, así que aquí esta el código resuelto y ejercicio resuelto.

#include 
#include

int main()
{

```
std::vector<int>vect;

int num;
int sumatoria = 0 ;
std::cout << "Introduce el tamaño de su matriz cuadrada: ";
std::cin >> num;



/// funciones        
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        float numero;
        std::cout << "Introduce los numeros deseados: ";
        std::cin >> numero;
        vect.push_back(numero); 
        
        ////sumatoria
        sumatoria = sumatoria + numero; 
    }          
}

if (sumatoria !=0){
    std::cout<<"No es una matriz de probabilidad";
}
else{
    std::cout<<"Es una matriz de probabilidad";
}   



    
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Ummm, yo creo que no esta bien, no validas que el número sea positivo, y la sumatoria es por cada fila que tiene que dar 1 y tu sumas toda la matriz